# How to store large amounts of data locally in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a mobile application in React Native with Expo. The application must be able to store data locally such as form data, images and information. I was using [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage) but the images make it exceed the limit of [6MB](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size), any other option to store large amounts of data?

**EDIT:** I have managed to store the images in base64 using Expo [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/), I just create a new document and convert the object to text when I save it

Comment: I would advise not storing / hosting large amounts of data locally.  As you can tell this already has an effect on your application, and will drain your users' battery life quickly which will deter them from using your app.  I would only store small bits of data locally and make use of cache storage for images.  Other than that, the rest of your data should reside in a remote database.

Comment: I really do not want to keep the data always saved, the application must work without internet and when there is an internet connection upload the data and delete it from the local storage. But I need to be able to have them local when I'm offline

Comment: Asyncstorage is not meant for storing images, only things like user preferred theme, locale… I would not recommend storing all the images in device unless you believe they will never change. If so you can just create a `images` folder and access them through JS